# How to set maximum concurrent connection for virtual host?

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd

If I have Apache virtual hosting, can I set maximum concurrent connection for each host?

I have an API service that get a lot of requests and starve the main site, can I limit the concurrent connection to http://api.example.com whereas http://example.com get more connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at mod-bw: http://apache.ivn.cl/#bandwidth (`libapache-mod-bw` on Debian).

But this doesn't really solve your problem, as now the clients that want to access `api.example.com` will run into problems. Can't you offload the API stuff to a separate server?

Answer (score 0):

Installing a 2nd apache on the same machine on a different IP (or port), or even an nginx or lighttpd would be my solution if you don't have the option to get a 2nd server.